# Creating a font or updating an existing font

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I want to make a font that links certain letters together when they are typed for example "au" would go together and "ll" would go together. I would also like these two letters together to be underlined when they are typed automatically. Century Gothic font or similar is a fine to use. Other single letters I would like a dot to appear below them. I wonder how I would go about doing this? Any advice welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: It may help if you [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/126057/edit) to explain a bit about how familiar you may be with font creation. In addition, tagging the question properly for your preferred front editing/creating software will lead to more targeted answers.

Comment: Depending on the type of link you want to create and the application you use. In InDesign it's possible to create GREP styles so when two specific characters are typed they appear in a certain way.

Comment: Thanks I will use InDesign. I have watched a video on GREP's looks really useful. How would I get it to display a dot below letters in a word that are not underlined? Thanks again Danielillo x

Comment: have you also looked into font ligatures?

Comment: @VCooper how to add dots below letters in a word in InDesign is a different question than *Creating a font or updating an existing font*. I will be glad to help you if you ask it.

Comment: I will close your question as it is because it is very broad and also not very clear what you want to achieve. You also seem to be suffering from an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554). I suggest to ask a new question detailing what you want to achieve and why. I strongly suggest that you make a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Editing a font is possible in font editor software. There are many of them available commercially and for free. There are a few problems:

- others do not have the modified font file, so they cannot print nor watch your documents which use that font (except if you have rasterized or outlined the texts or the font file is embedded) The document will be shown wrongly with a substituted font
- fonts are software and someone owns the copyright. Many font copyright owners such as Adobe have strictly forbidden making modified versions of font files and distributing font files even as is. They can have also created technical obstacles for it. Embedding the font inside a PDF is allowed in some cases, when distributing otherwise is strictly forbidden, but that does not help if creating a modified version is forbidden or technically prevented.

Some fonts are free to use, distribute and modify as long as you do it in the way the license states. At least renaming is a must and including all credits of original creators. You should start always with reading the license. If you do not find or understand it, don't make a modified version.

Seemingly you already have got an advice to solve the problem with typography rule settings. Check them first and avoid legal problems.