# How do I edit the metrics for a specific character in a font?

Tags: fonts, typography, open-source

Specifically, I want to modify two fonts so that the metrics for the space character (ASCII 32) in one font match the metrics of the other font.

Linux or Mac open source solutions preferred.

Comment: Traditionally such spacing is adjusted in a *layout application* and not directly in font files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a font or updating an existing font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126057/creating-a-font-or-updating-an-existing-font)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is an open source program that allows (among many other things) the user to edit the metrics for a particular character.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to edit an actual font or add multiple spaces to achieve indents, and in fact doing so would cause many undesirable problems. Anyone else on a different computer viewing/editing your document would not see the changes unless they installed the version of the font you altered. Also all spaces would be altered, not just the ones being used to indent the text. There are also legal considerations, such as the fact that most font licences do not allow modifying of font files or redistribution of those font files.

It's much easier to create indents using the software you are using to type/layout the document.

You can set indents using page layout software such as Scribus (open source Mac/Linux/Windows), or even word processing software such as LibreOffice Text (also open source).

This is for Scribus:

1. Type some lines of text in a text box
2. Change the fonts to whatever you want, set the point size as desired
3. Highlight the text you wish to indent, to select it
4. On the ruler above, click and drag the indent marker to the desired position

Example

[image]

Note: If for some (unknown) reason you must use spaces to achieve the indents, it's also possible to select the spaces and set them all to a particular font, even when the following text is in a different font.

Also, although I wouldn't recommend altering font files to achieve your desired indents, you would need font creation software to do it. FontForge is Open Source software which allows you to create or edit fonts. Note that it's highly complex software with a steep learning curve.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth answer.  I've updated my question to add a bit of context, mainly revolving around the fact that I'm pulling in some text from external source code files.  I'll give fontforge a go!

Comment: @MarkHarrison just as long as you know I don't recommend editing font files to achieve your desired results, for the reasons I already stated.

Comment: Acknowledging that, although I've published three computer books over the years (two for O'Reilly and one for Addison Wesley), and it's a standard practice for included source code.  You can see that as well on Stack Exchange where 4-space leading indentation indicates a code block.  But regardless, fiddling with FontForge produced the desired results, and I'm now able to swap between the two font families as desired without changing the meaning of the code, allowing me to hit the pedagogical goals of the formatting. FontForge is supported by Brew on Mac, so it was easy to install as well.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Whats wrong with search and replace? Anyway the real problem is the PDF files ignore start of the line whitespace ;)

Comment: @joojaa, think of a programming text, you have a page of explanation followed by a python function that does some particular task.  As you are writing the explanation in your word processor, you are simultaneously writing and testing that function in your code environment.  Multiply that by many pages of explanation and many code snippets, and you can see you get a seriously difficult synchronization problem.  This is solved by word processors or text processors being able to include source code directly.  In this case, you map them onto a paragraph type and font that preserves (continued...)

Comment: @joojaa (continued...) correct indentation and appearance. In my specific case, I need two fonts that can be used to present contrasting code blocks, but their metrics need to be similar enough that the spaced-indentation stays the same.  It's true that once it's boiled down to PDF the leading whitespace won't matter! :)

Comment: @MarkHarrison Yes i understand how code works. But i also understand how a typesetting engine works. There is nothing that stops a good software to automatically convert number of spaces to indentations. Both InDesign and Scribus as well as tex is capable of doing this, this invalidates need to change font.

Comment: @joojaa, sorry i'm not making myself clear.  I want to use two different code fonts, and make sure their indentation stays consistent.  The choice of fonts is strictly based on stylistic concerns in order to promote the pedagogical goals of the book.  It's working well, the only problem I had was that the two fonts had different metrics for the space character, causing problems in the rendering of the examples. Changing that with FontForge fixed everything.

Comment: I understand that, im just saying your solution is far from ideal. @MarkHarrison There are a lot of problems with your approach, one being that you now have a custom font that nn oboby else has. But it also prevents you from easily changing that font whch can become a problem for your print house. A lot of software can easily adress the issue without needing you to change the font.

Comment: I think joojaa is saying that you are asking for help with the wrong solution: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @joojaa, I appreciate the comments, but my publishers (O'Reilly and Addison Wesley) are fine with this approach, and it's one we've used for several books before.  I've typeset and turned over camera-ready copy for both houses and it's been fine.  I just had a busted font!

Comment: @Yorik, thanks for that pointer!  I'm going to have to disagree with joojaa though.  I've been typesetting my own books professionally for nearly 25 years, and typesetting technical docs going back to Scribe since about 1982.  I'm happy to fix a busted font.  I was referred here from meta, but maybe there's a better place to be asking font-related questions.  I no longer have access to Illustrator, which is why I was hoping to find something in open source-land.  Which I did, with much appreciation to Billy Kerr for the FontForge pointer.  Everything's good now, no more busted font!

Answer (score 0):

Applications like Illustrator and InDesign have a Tabs option in Paragraph Styles. Otherwise a program like "Glyphs" on the Apple store you could adjust things like that.